# WPF: Access XAML objects/shapes/path declared using C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a newbie in WPF and I would like to ask if it's possible to access my WPF ojects using C#.

Here is a line of code from WPF:

```
<Path x:Name="layout1"
      Fill="Red" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Red"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="374.714,140.786,0,0"
      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116.215" Height="109.571"
      Data="M374.71429,204.14286 L387.07172,249.357 489.9328,157.92762 451.36006,140.78486 428.50213,157.92762 409.21576,173.64206 390.6437,189.35651 z"
      />
```

How would I access 'layout1' (**using C#**) in such a way that I could change its visibility into 'hidden'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    layout1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

in any code-behind method.

Comment: Thanks! I just forgot the x:FieldModifier="public"

Answer (score 1):

The path is automatically accessible in the code-behind file, using the name specified in **x:Name**, in this case **layout1**.
If you'd like to also access it from a place other than the code-behind file, you should add

```
x:FieldModifier="public"
```

to the tag. This way, it get a publicly accessible attribute for the object the path is in. Again, you access it through the name specified in **x:Name**.